# org-mode: Scheduling item that lasts longer than one day

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Is it possible to place a list-item scheduled for a period lasting longer than one day? The item should then be displayed in this when I hit `C-c a a` for `agenda-view`.

My pathetic workaround consists of placing multiple entries, one for each day, something like this:

```
* Weekend Workshop
** DATE Day 1 Workshop
SCHEDULED: <2018-08-04 Sa>
** DATE Day 2 Workshop
SCHEDULED: <2018-08-05 Su>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with:

```
* Weekend Workshop
** DATE Workshop
SCHEDULED: <2018-08-04 Sa>--<2018-08-05 Su>
```

The Org manual is normally very good for this kind of info: [Timestamps, deadlines, and scheduling](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Timestamps)